# What will happen if Gravitational force go off!

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, thought-experiment

One day I was thinking, what will happen if Gravitational force goes off ?? 
Will the planet go away from it's orbit?? 
OR
The planet will drop down or go up or roam randomly ?? 
You have to explain. 
☺☺

The tricky thing is that if the planet gravitational force goes off suddenly then how it will get attracted by Sun.
Have you thought about this?? 
How can I apply Newton's law of gravity?? 
That's why I am asking ☺☺

Comment: Have you tried using [Newton's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion) yourself ?  What did you get ?

Comment: I don't know how to apply.

Comment: Can you explain 

Answer (score 2):

If gravity goes off suddenly,

Current state of all interstellar objects are either in elliptical or circular orbits due gravity.

Every objects will move straight in the tangential direction at the time when gravity stops.

On earth every individual objects will experience 0 gravity and earth becomes inhabitable. Because atmosphere escapes as no force acts on air to stay on earth.